# service : The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the above error. I have attached the code. Whenever I call the service in the else part i cant able to _creditMISMOErrorRepository.AddRange(errList), throwing this error. Please help thanks in advance.

The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Comment: what does your autofac config look like. specifically the registration of the xRepository and UnitOfWork classes and the corresponding ef context they are using.

Comment: i just mentioned autofac for question conflict.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: i am not aware of autofac config

Comment: how are you configuring autofac?  What are the lifestyle/lifetime settings are you using when you register your repositories and uow.  If they are 'transient' you are probably creating a new instance of your dbcontext every time which would result in this error since each repo is getting it's own instance of dbcontext.  you would need to use a factory method or possibly change the lifestyle for the dbcontext to be "per web request" so that only 1 context is created per request.

Comment: builder.RegisterType<R2Context>().As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: update your question with the relevant code

Comment: this is ly my code